# Is the following code asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, generator

While reading the (highly recommended) book series [*You Don't Know JS*](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS), I read [this](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20%26%20performance/ch4.md#iterating-generators-asynchronously) part:

```
function foo(x,y,cb) {
    ajax(
        "http://some.url.1/?x=" + x + "&y=" + y,
        cb
    );
}

foo( 11, 31, function(err,text) {
    if (err) {
        console.error( err );
    }
    else {
        console.log( text );
    }
} );
```

As you can clearly see, the call to function `foo` is completely async by [wiki definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony_(computer_programming)):

> Asynchrony, in computer programming, refers to the occurrence of events independent of the main program flow and ways to deal with such events. These may be "outside" events such as the arrival of signals, or actions instigated by a program that take place concurrently with program execution, ***without the program blocking to wait for results***.

The author reimplemented the above code using `generators` to demonstrate how `generators` are used when we want to execution async functions:

```
function foo(x,y) {
    ajax(
        "http://some.url.1/?x=" + x + "&y=" + y,
        function(err,data){
            if (err) {
                // throw an error into `*main()`
                it.throw( err );
            }
            else {
                // resume `*main()` with received `data`
                it.next( data );
            }
        }
    );
}

function *main() {
    try {
        var text = yield foo( 11, 31 );
        console.log( text );
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error( err );
    }
}

var it = main();

// start it all up!
it.next();
```

By calling `it.next()` we execute `main` until the first `yield` and then wait until the iterator `it` will resume `main` execution. By definition of async, the call following piece of codes are not async:

```
function *main() {
    try {
        var text = yield foo( 11, 31 );
        console.log( text );
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error( err );
    }
}
```

And:

```
var it = main();

// start it all up!
it.next();
```

---

Are any of my conclusions incorrect?

Comment: that code is not nice

Comment: I can see an advantage: this is the cleanest code for extracting a callback's result back to the caller without registering more events for using that result.

Comment: @Isaac [After reading that chapter](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20%26%20performance/ch4.md), I can say that this code is extremely powerful and is the first step to implement `async` and `await`. I encourage you to read this chapter to better understand how this code evolves to something much more solid and strong.

Comment: You're using a global variable, `it`, this defeats the purpose of trying to untangle your code

Comment: I thought so also. But then he slowly upgraded this code (step by step) to a much better one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the author of YDKJS. The first `it.next()` call to run, the one on the last line of the second snippet, is indeed **synchronous**, but the text isn't claiming otherwise. Rather, just as in the first cited snippet, the text is asserting that the second `it.next(..)` call is asynchronous.

The code is assuming that the `ajax(..)` call is actually making its call asynchronously, so that its response (the invoking of that callback) is also asynchronous. Thus, the second invocation of `it.next(..)` -- the one that resumes the paused `yield foo(..)` call -- which inside of that callback, has in fact happened asynchronously.

In other words, the `yield foo(..)` pauses that generator locally, while the Ajax call processes, which allows any of the rest of the JS program to run, and when the Ajax response comes back, the `it.next(..)` call resumes the generator... asynchronously.

Hope that clears things up.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. It was extremely helpful. It's recommended for who reads this question to print something after `it.next();` and see that it will be printed before everything; the code is fully async.